# .asp pages will not update

Tags: html, caching, asp-classic

I'm working on a project for a client who's site was developed years ago with .asp.

I am implementing a new design (html/css) and have been going through the .asp pages and removing the old HTML and replacing it with the new code, developed by me.

The Pages show no change when the page is loaded live on the website. When I open the .asp file in a text editor, the new code is there. I've read up on this and it seems like the server may be caching the .asp files, but I do not know how to clear this cache, as I am simply editing the files in a simple text editor (textmate).

Comment: Version of IIS would be useful?  Which browsers have you tried?

Comment: I have no info on the IIS. I (for some reason) thought I could add HTML / CSS to the pages without access to that. I'm downloding the files with Cyber Duck and Editing with Textmate - this is the only software I am using. Tried in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Turns out is was a simple IIS setting that was being over-ruled by another. The network admin found the fix.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: What was the IIS setting (or settings) that needed to be fixed?  (Could be helpful for future visitors who see this question)

Comment: Please share your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Usually forcing a browser refresh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> should refresh the page on the server. In rare cases, you'll have to do this for every page. Experienced and solved it this way in IIS 5 and IIS 6, so if the same condition is happening for you in later versions of IIS, try it.

Comment: Forget to mention that you should do this in Internet Explorer (6, 7, 8 or 9 - it works for me in all of those versions) and then it'll work after a normal refresh in most other browsers.

Answer (score -2):

Did you clear the browser cache? Based on NET framework for ASP pages, temporary files are created at %Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\Temporary ASP.NET Files. Remove any files created there and refresh ASP page using CTRL+F5.

Comment: The question refers to classic ASP not asp.net.